# Theorem 10, Section 2.5 of Hungerford’s Abstract Algebra

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation, group-actions, sylow-theory

> **Theorem 5.10.** (Third Sylow Theorem) If $G$ is a finite group and $p$ a prime, then the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$ divides $|G|$ and is of the form $kp+1$ for some $k\geq O$.
>
> **Proof:** By the second Sylow Theorem the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups is the number of conjugates of any one of them, say $P$. But this number is $[G:N_G(P)]$, a divisor of $|G|$, by Corollary 4.4. Let $S$ be the set of all Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$ and let $P$ act on $S$ by conjugation. Then $Q\in S_0$ if and only if $xQx^{1}= Q$ for all $x\in P$. The latter condition holds if and only if $P \lt N_G(Q)$. Both $P$ and $Q$ are Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$ and hence of $N_G(Q)$ and are therefore conjugate in $N_G(Q)$. But since $Q$ is normal in $N_G(Q)$, this can only occur if $Q = P$. Therefore, $S_0 =\{P\}$ and by Lemma 5.1, $|S|=|S_0|= 1\pmod p$. Hence $|S|=kp+1$.

**Question:** I don’t understand “But since $Q$ is normal in $N_G(Q)$, this can only occur if $Q = P$” sentence. By second Sylow theorem, $\exists x\in N_G(Q)=\{g\in G\mid gQg^{-1}=Q\}$ such that $P=xQx^{-1}=Q$. We’re simply using definition of $N_G(P)$.

I think, Author should have added $|G|=p^nm$ where $(p,m)=1$ (or equivalently $p$ divides $|G|$) condition in the hypothesis to guarantee existence of Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$.

---

**Edit:** I see why Author phrase that sentence in that particular way. If $P$ is Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ and normal in $G$, then $P$ is the only Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. It’s proof follows directly from second Sylow theorem.

Comment: A Sylow $p$-subgroup exists for every prime and every finite group. If $p$ does not divide $|G|$, then by definition the trivial subgroup is a (in fact, the) Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$, since it is a maximal $p$-subgroup of $G$ (the definition used by Hungerford). The trivial group satisfies his definition of $p$-subgroup.  You say you "don't understand" the assertion, and then provide a proof of that assertion. So what do you not understand?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I am not sure whether Author consider trivial subgroup as Sylow $p$-subgroup. Because for finite group Author gave equivalent definition of Sylow $p$-subgroup, which states “$H$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ if and only if $|H| = p^n$”, $n\geq 1$ is explicitly assumed. By understand, I mean we don’t need to use normality condition. Why author phrase that sentence in slightly convoluted way? Is there a specific reason or general result?

Comment: Your lack of certainty is immaterial, given that the author gives an explicit definition of both "Sylow $p$-subgroup" and "$p$-subgroup" and explicitly allows the trivial group in both. In Section II.5, before Corollary 5.3, Hungerford writes "A group in which every element has order a power ($\geq 0$) of some fixed prime $p$ is called a **p-group**. If $H$ is a subgroup of a group $G$ and $H$ is a $p$-group, $H$ is said to be a **p-subgroup** of $G$. In particular, $\langle e\rangle$ is a $p$-subgroup of $G$ for every prime $p$, since $|\langle e\rangle|=1=p^0$." (cont)

Comment: (cont) And after Theorem 5.7, Hungerford writes: "A subgroup $P$ of a group $G$ is said to be a **Sylow p-subgroup** ($p$ a prime) if $P$ is a maximal $p$-subgroup of $G$ (that is, $P\lt H\lt G$ with $H$ a $p$-group implies $P=H$). Sylow $p$-subgroups always exist, though they may be trivial, and every $p$-subgroup is contained in a Sylow $p$-subgroup[.]" So Hungerford **explicitly** says that the trivial subgroup may be a Sylow $p$-subgroup.

Comment: What you quote is not a definition, but a Corollary (Corollary 5.8), which is stated with the explicit assumption that $|G|=p^nm$ with $n\geq 1$ and $\gcd(p,m)=1$. That is then not an "equivalent definition of Sylow $p$-subgroup". It is a Corollary/Theorem that says that under certain conditions, a subgroup will be a Sylow $p$-subgroup if and only if it has that order. Not a definition, or a statement saying this is equivalent to the definition of Sylow $p$-subgroup in all circumstances. It is a statement that for groups that satisfy **that** property, it is equivalent, and nothing more.

Comment: Put your "doubt" in the post, not buried in the comments. Of course you are using the normality condition. How else do you conclude $xQx^{-1}=Q$? By definition, $N_G(Q)$ is the largest subgroup of $G$ in which $Q$ is normal. Using "$Q$ is normal in $N_G(Q)$" is the same as using its definition. There is nothing convoluted about the sentence, lightly or otherwise.